# Change Orientation in iOS 5.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, frame, uiinterfaceorientation

I am creating one project in viewcontroller. I have image view, labels and `scrollview`. But when I change the orientation its aligning in bad way?

Is there any way to align correctly? Also my scrollview is not working. I set the delegate as view in storyboard.my controll frame are(landscape mode).

```
    book_cover_image.frame=CGRectMake(50,20,250,300);
    label_book_name.frame=CGRectMake(350,20,500,50);
    label_book_author.frame=CGRectMake(350,76 , 500, 50);
    label_book_price.frame=CGRectMake(350,135, 500, 50);
    image_price_rupees.frame=CGRectMake(100, 330, 22, 16);
    [buy_button setFrame:CGRectMake(13, 380, 119, 32)];
    [preview_button setFrame:CGRectMake(150, 380, 113, 32)];
    RecommendedBooksView.frame=CGRectMake(0,400,1024,368);
    _thumbnailListView.frame=CGRectMake(15, 50, 950,350);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using autoresizingMask property of UIView to automatically resize and reposition views during rotation.

http://www.techpaa.com/2012/05/understanding-uiview-autoresizing.html

If the autoresizingMask cannot do what you want, you can customize the frame for each orientation by implementing:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        //set new frame properties
    }];
}
```

in your view controller.